React Native image cropping
I am quite new to React Native and Expo, so excuse my ignorance.  I am building an app with Expo (RN: 0.74.1, Expo: 51.0.8) that requires showing an image from an external URL and being able to crop it.  I already implemented a version where I use the ImagePicker, but this requires that I have to save the image to the user's pictures and then ask them to select it from there.  I am looking for a way to crop the image directly without having to save the file and pop the picker.
I was looking at https://github.com/st0ffern/react-native-image-cropper, but I am concerned that the plugin is quite old (the last version is from 2017).  I could not find anything else suitable.  I did find a few React components, but I am not sure if I can use those in React Native.
I was also looking for a way to pop the Image Picker with an image already selected, but I could not find anything in the docs that allows me to do that.
Any suggestions on how to proceed?

 *Using react-native-image-crop-picker
    import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';
    
    ImagePicker.openCropper({
      path: 'https://example.com/image.jpg',
      width: 300,
      height: 400
    }).then(image => {
      console.log(image);
    });
 *Using expo-image-crop
    import { ImageCrop } from 'expo-image-crop';
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { View, Button, Image } from 'react-native';
    
    const App = () => {
      const [croppedImage, setCroppedImage] = useState(null);
    
      const handleCrop = async () => {
        const result = await ImageCrop.openCropper({
          uri: 'https://example.com/image.jpg',
          aspect: [4, 3]
        });
        setCroppedImage(result.uri);
      };
    
      return (
        <View>
          <Button title="Crop Image" onPress={handleCrop} />
          {croppedImage && <Image source={{ uri: croppedImage }} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />}
        </View>
      );
    };
    
    export default App;
 *Using react-native-image-editor with Expo
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { View, Button, Image } from 'react-native';
    import ImageEditor from '@react-native-community/image-editor';
    
    const App = () => {
      const [croppedImage, setCroppedImage] = useState(null);
    
      const handleCrop = async () => {
        const cropData = {
          offset: { x: 0, y: 0 },
          size: { width: 300, height: 300 },
          displaySize: { width: 300, height: 300 },
          resizeMode: 'contain',
        };
    
        ImageEditor.cropImage('https://example.com/image.jpg', cropData).then((uri) => {
          setCroppedImage(uri);
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
      };
    
      return (
        <View>
          <Button title="Crop Image" onPress={handleCrop} />
          {croppedImage && <Image source={{ uri: croppedImage }} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />}
        </View>
      );
    };
    
    export default App;


Thank you Anu. I will try those and will report back
